# How to interpret DateListPlot FrameTicks in Mathematica 11

Tags: plotting, date-and-time

In Mathematica 7 frame ticks from a `DateListPlot` were amenable to editing.  How can I obtain this information from `DateListPlot` in Mathematica 11?

For example, extracting frame ticks like so:

```
Options[DateListPlot[{
   {{2006, 10, 1}, 10},
   {{2006, 10, 15}, 12},
   {{2006, 10, 30}, 15},
   {{2006, 11, 20}, 20}}], FrameTicks]
```

Mathematica 7 output - easy to edit and replace.

```
{FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic},
   {{{3368736000, "Oct 02"}, {3369945600, "Oct 16"}, {3371155200, "Oct 30"},
     {3372364800, "Nov 13"}, {3373574400, "Nov 27"}, {3369340800, ""},
     {3370550400, ""}, {3371760000, ""}, {3372969600, ""}},
    {{3368736000, ""}, {3369945600, ""}, {3371155200, ""}, {3372364800, ""},
     {3373574400, ""}, {3369340800, ""}, {3370550400, ""}, {3371760000, ""},
     {3372969600, ""}}}}}
```

Mathematica 11 output - not in plain format.

```
{FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic},
   {Charting`FindScaledTicks[
      (Charting`getDateTicks[Automatic, {Automatic},
          (DateList /@ {##1} &)[##1], None, 5, {{0.0125, 0}, {0.0075, 0}},
          Automatic] &)[##1], {Identity, Identity}] &,
    Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[
      (Charting`getDateTicks[
          Charting`getDateTicks[Automatic, {Automatic},
            (DateList /@ {##1} &)[##1], None, 5, {{0.0125, 0}, {0.0075, 0}},
            Automatic] &, {Automatic}, (DateList /@ {##1} &)[##1], None, 5,
          {{0.0125, 0}, {0.0075, 0}}, None] &)[##1], {Identity, Identity}] &}}}
```

Comment: something to start with: `Function[plotInput,
  Options[DateListPlot[plotInput], FrameTicks][[1, 2, 2, 1]] @@ 
   plotInput[[{1, -1}, 1]]
  ]@{{{2006, 10, 1}, 10}, {{2006, 10, 15}, 12}, {{2006, 10, 30}, 
   15}, {{2006, 11, 20}, 20}}` don't know what is the proper workflow.

Comment: @Kuba Terrific! It works, although I haven't figured out how. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ticks function is fed with `Sequence[min, max]`. So,

```
ticksfun = 
Charting`FindScaledTicks[(Charting`getDateTicks[
    Automatic, {Automatic}, (DateList /@ {##1} &)[##1], None, 
    5, {{0.0125, 0}, {0.0075, 0}}, Automatic] &)[##1], {Identity, 
 Identity}] &;
```

result:

```
In[4]:= ticksfun[{2006, 10, 1}, {2006, 11, 20}]

Out[4]= {{3.36874*10^9, "Oct 02", {0.00833333, 0}}, {3.36995*10^9, 
"Oct 16", {0.00833333, 0}}, {3.37116*10^9, 
"Oct 30", {0.00833333, 0}}, {3.37236*10^9, 
"Nov 13", {0.00833333, 0}}, {3.37357*10^9, 
"Nov 27", {0.00833333, 0}}, {3.36874*10^9, 
Spacer[{0, 0}], {0.00833333, 0}}, {3.36934*10^9, 
Spacer[{0, 0}], {0.00833333, 0}}, {3.36995*10^9, 
Spacer[{0, 0}], {0.00833333, 0}}, {3.37055*10^9, 
Spacer[{0, 0}], {0.00833333, 0}}, {3.37116*10^9, 
Spacer[{0, 0}], {0.00833333, 0}}, {3.37176*10^9, 
Spacer[{0, 0}], {0.00833333, 0}}, {3.37236*10^9, 
Spacer[{0, 0}], {0.00833333, 0}}, {3.37297*10^9, 
Spacer[{0, 0}], {0.00833333, 0}}}
```